# How to use tokenpassport in netsuite in java

Tags: java, netsuite

I have generated Tokenpassort in java but I do not see how to use it in Java.
All samples I have seen are in C#

1) NetSuiteServiceLocator does not take tokenpassport

2) NetSuiteService is an interface.

3) NSPORT takes in passport but NOT tokenpassport.

How to use tokenpassport in Java ( not C# ) ?

Answer (score 0):

**SHORT ANSWER:**  The token goes into a SOAP Header named "tokenPassport" in the SoapEnvelope.  One way to make that happen is via the javax.xml.rpc.Stub class's setHeader method.

**HERE'S WHAT WORKED FOR ME:**

```
    import org.apache.axis.client.Stub;
    import org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement;
    import com.netsuite.webservices.platform.core_2019_1.TokenPassport;    // WSDL version 2019.1
    import com.netsuite.webservices.platform_2019_1.NetSuitePortType; // WSDL version 2019.1`<br/>

    TokenPassport tokenPassport = ...;
    NetSuitePortType port = ...;`<br/>

    String namespace = "urn:messages_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"; // WSDL version 2019.1
    SOAPHeaderElement tokenPassportHeader = 
        new SOAPHeaderElement(nameSpace, "tokenPassport", tokenPassport);
    ((Stub) port).setHeader(tokenPassportHeader);
```

**NOTE:**
The *_2019_1 packages are soap client packages generated by Axis using NetSuite's WSDL for version 2019.1.

**ONE OTHER PITFALL:**  The algorithm name that NetSoft expects in TokenPassportSignature.algoritm is NOT the same as the name used in java's SecretKeySpec constructor.  For example, the SecretKeySpec uses "HmacSHA256", but TokenPassportSignature expects "HMAC-SHA256".